# Clustering of one variable based on another variable

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to make clusters of different countries based on their GDP per capita. In our example, we use the GDP per capita for each year and have different years represented in our dataset.

How can we cluster these countries easily in R?

[picture of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAKoS.png)

Comment: I this the plase to start is reading `?cut()`

Comment: If you want to group them manually, use `cut()`, if not, pick a clustering algorithm and search for "how to <name of clustering algorithm> in R", e.g, "how to kmeans clustering in r".

Comment: Do not upload pictures of your data. The image you provided does not even include all of the columns you describe. Provide a sample of your data using `dput()` and paste the text into your question. Alternatively, find an R data set that is similar enough to be an example and tell us what it is.